# ER Diagram Participation Constraints in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to understand converting ER diagrams into SQL CREATE statements, but I am having a hard time with understanding how participation constraints work. In an ER diagram a participation constrain is represented by a bold line which means that every tuple in the table must appear in the relationship table. If there is a participation constraint and a key constraint (total) it is possible to fulfil the key constrain.

Is there ever a situation in which there is a way to enforce a participation constraint that isn't also a key constraint without using assertions or check constraints?

***Edit***

I was more confused about the whole concept as opposed to one particular example, but I was able to find an example that I drew out the diagram for that would illustrate my confusion. In the picture below we have a participation constraint and a key constraint from professors to teachers; therefore every professor must teach 1 class and only 1 class. This constraint can be enforced by having a professors_teach table as opposed to having two separate tables; by making the professors ssn the primary key there will only ever be 1 entry for each professor in the professors_teach table, and since it will have all the records that normally would be put in the professors table then every professor must be in the new table.

My confusion is in the participation constraint from course to teacher; basically what the diagram is saying is that every course must have at least one teacher; which I don't think can be enforced without using assertions or check constraints.

[image]

Comment: Your question isnt clear. If you explain what you want to do or explain what are the class involve. Or show us the diagram ER we can do more

Comment: i've added an example to clarify my confusion. Mind you, it isn't a particular example that is confusing me, but rather the actual concept; Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For this case you dont need a relatioship.

You only need table teacher, and define the field `course_id (unique)`. In this case you have teachers and they can have 0 or 1 course. And each course will be teach for only one teacher.

```
 teacher_id (primary key)
 teacher_name
 ssn
 course_id (unique) fk reference courses(course_id)
```

Courses

```
 course_id  (primary key)
 course_name
```

But you shouldnt enforce every course have teacher in the db because a new course will need a teacher right away. Is better you insert the course and then assign a teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You merge the relation Teaches and the Entity Professor in:

```
CREATE TABLE Prof_teaches(
  ssn INTEGER,
  semesterid INTEGER,
  courseID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY courseID REFERENCES Course (courseid),
  PRIMARY KEY ssn
)

CREATE TABLE Course(
  courseid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
)
```

This is for total participation and key constraint as defined in the Book by Ramakrishnan. Meaning that each Professor (note, single f), participates in al least (total participation) and at most (key constraint) one teaches relationship.